# Excel VBA to Work Across Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA coding and don't have very good understanding of what I am doing to be honest. But here I go.

I am looking to see if:

- Can VBA codes have dyname values? So instead of the code saying execute on a set sheet (e.g "Sheet1") that value changes depending a value in a certain cell.
- To trigger a VBA on another workbook. For example I want to run a VBA from **Workbook A** that triggers a VBA on **Workbook B**.

To fully explain I want to open **Workbook A** (and **Workbook B** if needed, it doesn't matter) and click a button that runs a VBA on **Workbook B** but on a certain Sheet depending on the value of a cell in **Excel A** (if the cell says "sheet3" the VBA runs on "sheet3" on **Workbook B**). I also want cells in **Workbook A** to reference cells in **Workbook B** but the the sheet name to by dynamic. For example I have pasted the basic cell reference bellow but instead of having `Sheet1` I want it to change depending on the value in a cell.

```
='[Workbook B.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$4
```

I know this sounds very complicates and confusing, but if I could get any help that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ReportStepOne() 
    Dim myRow As Long 

    myRow = 4 
    Rows(myRow).Value = Rows(myRow).Value 

    Dim rng As Range 
    Set rng = Range("A4:AC200") 
    rng.Cut rng.Offset(1, 0) 
    Range("A1:AC1").Copy Range("A4:AC4") 
End Sub
```

I want to:

1. edit this code to make it fire on a certain sheet
2. make it so the sheet name is referenced to whatever is in cell A o Sheet2 in Report.xlsm.
3. Run a macro in Report.xlsm that runs the above script (which is called "StepOne" in a file called "Historical Data.xlsm"

Comment: In which workbook does the above code reside, `Report.xlsm` or `Historical Data.xlsm`? If I understand correctly this code should execute on a sheet in `Report.xlsm`, which sheet is based on a cell on sheet2 in `Report.xlsm`

Comment: The code is on `Historical data.xlsm` and currently fires on the active sheet. I'm hoping to make it fire on a specific sheet, in which the macro references the "sheet name" from a cell in `Reports.xlsm`. 
Then have a macro/button in `Reports.xlsm` that makes the above macro run. 

It's a new reporting system that I am trying to develop (I'll have to run this macro approximately 40 times). 

Thanks for your help @SilentRevolution. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: so the above code sits in `historical data.xlsm` needs to reference a worksheet to retrieve a worksheet name in `reports.xlsm` and then execute the code. the sheet named on sheet 2 of  `reports.xlsm` does that referer to a sheet in `historical data` or to a sheet on `reports.xlsm`? Do you always have both workbooks open at the same time, if not which workbook is open?

Comment: The code would reference cell A4 on Sheet2 in `reports.xlsm`. Yeah the sheet name in `reports.xlsm` refers to a sheet name in `historical data.xlsm`. Cell A4 in `reports.xlsm` will automatically update with a new clients name, and each client has there own sheet in `historical data.xlsm`. I'll have both files open at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below takes the value of cell A4 on sheet2 in `Reports.xlsm` and sets the ws variable to the sheet in `Historical data.xlsm` which is then used for the rest of the code. If possible I'd advise against having your subs spread out over multiple projects but that is just my opinion. I think it is easier to use proper referencing like below.

Since you want a button trigger on the `Report.xlsm` I'd suggest moving this code to that workbook. If properly referenced it you can open, edit, save and close any workbook from a single project which again, in my opinion is easier than calling subs in a different project.

```
Sub ReportStepOne()
    Dim wbHis As Workbook, wbRep As Workbook
    Dim strWsName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wbHis = Workbooks("Historical data.xlsm")
    Set wbRep = Workbooks("Reports.xlsm")

    strWsName = wbRep.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 1)
    Set ws = wbHis.Worksheets(strWsName)

    With ws
        With .Rows(4)
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        With .Range("A4:AC200")
            .Cut .Offset(1, 0)
        End With
        .Range("A1:AC1").Copy .Range("A4:AC4")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You.Are.Amazing! This works perfectly!! 
Thank you so much @SilentRevolution. Your help was beyond generous.

Answer (score 0):

*To trigger a VBA on another workbook*

```
Option Explicit
Sub RunVBA()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Workbook


    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Om3r\Desktop\Book1.xlsm")
    xlApp.Visible = True

    xlWorkBook.Application.Run "Module1.SubName" ' Modulename.Subname

End Sub
```

*To reference worksheet use*

```
Sub CopyRange()
    '// From sheet1 to sheet2
    Worksheets(2).Range("A1").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. This is my code so far

`Sub ReportStepOne()
Dim myRow As Long
myRow = 4
Rows(myRow).Value = Rows(myRow).Value

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A4:AC200")
rng.Cut rng.Offset(1, 0)

Range("A1:AC1").Copy Range("A4:AC4")
End Sub`



I want to:
a) edit this code to make it fire on a certain sheet 
b) make it so the sheet name is referenced to whatever is in cell A on Sheet2 in Report.xlsm.


Then run a macro in Report.xlsm that runs the above script (which is called "StepOne" in a file called "Historical Data.xlsm" 

I know that I am asking a lot, sorry.

Comment: Ok I have worked out how to specify for the VBA to trigger on a specific sheet `MySheetName = "Clients"` (yes very complex stuff) I just need the change "Clients" to reference a cell in another workbook.